# Read .doc file using phpoffice

Tags: codeigniter-3, phpoffice

currently, I am using phpoffice for doc reader. but there is a problem with the .doc file preview. work well in the .docx file but the problem in.doc file. how can I fix this issue?

i Used `$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($source, 'Word2007');`